# Open VS2015 soulution/project in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd like to compile *Quake 2* sources in my `VS2019`. [There](https://github.com/oraoto/quake2-vs2015) is already an Q2 `VS2015` solution/project. Can i just open the `VS2015` `sln` in `VS2019` and compile the code successfully or have i do some conversion/preparation?

Comment: If you open it from inside VS2019 then any conversions required should be performed automatically. You *may* also need to change one or two project settings to conform to newer standards.

Comment: Ok, what project settings have i to chage?